# query update table based on key from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am figuring out about how mapping with query (based on key). I got the answer like this,

```
UPDATE Table1
   SET group1 = CASE customer_code
       WHEN 'a' THEN 'groupAB'
       WHEN 'b' THEN 'groupAC'
   END,
   group2 = CASE customer_code
       WHEN 'a' THEN 'group12'
       WHEN 'b' THEN 'group13'

   END
WHERE customer_code IN ('a','b')
```

But, it takes a lot of efforts when there's so many keys for examples I have more than hundred keys, mapping it, and update it to a table.

My question is, is there any query that effortless to update based on same key from 2 tables. I got this query,

```
update Table1 t1
set
  (
    t1.group1
      ) = (
    select
      t2.group2
    from
      Table2 t2
    where
      t2.name2 = t1.name1
     )
```

But, I always got error message like *'Line 2: Incorrect syntax near 't1'*
Is using alias not properly work here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add another table with key and group mapping and do join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use this syntax :

```
UPDATE
    Table1
SET
    Table1.group1 = Table2.group2
FROM
    Table1
INNER JOIN
    Table2
ON
    Table1.name = Table2.name
```